# Rolling annotations in gganimate

Tags: r

I'm making dynamic home run plots using these data frames. Here's an example of what it would look like for this player's home runs.

```
MorelHR <- data.frame(
 ID = c(663611, 663611), 
 launch_speed = c(98.2, 94.5), 
 launch_angle = c(26, 37), 
 hit_distance_sc = c(390, 362), 
 HR = c(1, 2), 
 Opponent = c("CLE", "CWS"), 
 x_coord = c(-115.2, -189.7), 
 y_coord = c(374.3, 310.4))
                
Positions <- data.frame(
 HR = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
 player_name2 = c("Bo Naylor", "Josh Bell", "Andrés Gimenez", "Amed Rosario", "Tyler Freeman", 
"David Fry", "Myles Straw", "Will Brennan", "Yasmani Grandal", "Gavin Sheets", "Elvis Andrus", 
"Tim Anderson", "Yoán Moncada", "Andrew Benintendi", "Luis Robert", "Oscar Colás"), 
 fielder_x = c(0, 57.5, 50, -50, -57.5, -130, 0, 130, 0, 57.5, 50, -50, -57.5, -130, 0, 130), 
 fielder_y = c(-20, 60, 120, 120, 60, 220, 310, 220, -20, 60, 120, 120, 60, 220, 310, 220))
```

Here's the code and packages required to run my animated plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbplotr)
library(geommlbstadiums)
library(ggtext)
library(gganimate)
    
MorelHR %>%
ggplot(aes(x = x_coord, y = y_coord)) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = x_coord, yend = y_coord)) +
geom_spraychart(stadium_ids = "cubs", stadium_transform_coords = T, stadium_segments = "all") +
geom_point(color = "red", size = 3) +
geom_label(data = Positions, aes(x = fielder_x, y = fielder_y, label = player_name2,
                                               color = color2, fill = color1, fontface = "bold")) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-325, 325)) +
annotate(GeomMLBheads, player_id = 663611, width = 0.5, x = -225, y = 10) +
              annotate(GeomMLBscoreboardlogo, team_abbr = MorelHR$Opponent, width = 0.1, x = 0, y = 210) +
annotate(GeomMLBscoreboardlogo, team_abbr = "STL", width = 0.1, x = 0, y = 210) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), color = "black", fill = NA) +
labs(title = "Home Run Count: {current_frame}",
                   subtitle = paste("v.", "**{filter(MorelHR, HR == current_frame) %>% pull(player_name2) %>% .[[1]]}**", "|",
                                    "**{filter(MorelHR, HR == current_frame) %>% pull(launch_speed) %>% .[[1]]}**", "mph |",
                                    "**{filter(MorelHR, HR == current_frame) %>% pull(launch_angle) %>% .[[1]]}**", "degrees |",
                                    "**{filter(MorelHR, HR == current_frame) %>% pull(hit_distance_sc) %>% .[[1]]}**", "ft"),
                   caption = "Data courtesy of MLB Advanced Media | **@GoCubs49**", x = NULL, y = NULL) +
theme_void() +
theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20), plot.subtitle = element_markdown(hjust = 0.5, size = 18),
                    plot.caption = element_markdown(size = 11, hjust = 0.98)) +
              scale_color_identity() +
              scale_fill_identity() +
              guides(color = "none", fill = "none") +
              transition_manual(HR) +
              enter_fade() +
              ease_aes("linear")
```

That code returns this animated plot.

[image]

I want the logo in the middle to change for the opposing team. In this case, it's fixed on the St. Louis Cardinals (team_abbr = "STL). However, as indicated in the MorelHR data frame, Madrigal's home runs came against the Cleveland Guardians ("CLE") and Chicago White Sox ("CWS"). Is it possible to make his change? If so, how can I go about it. Thank you! If you have any further questions, please ask and I'd be happy to clarify.